# How can I install a curtain rod so that it doesn't slide on the mounting brackets when opening and closing the curtains?

Tags: windows

I am hoping to install some drapes in our bedroom. In my experience, the curtain rod always slides into itself or over the mounting hardware while I am opening or closing the curtains. Is there a way I can mount it so that it stays static while I open and close the drapes?

Comment: A picture of the mounting brackets and rod might be useful.

Comment: Usually there are screws on the mounts that hold the rod right

Comment: Buy higher quality curtain rods.

Answer (score 15):

Typically curtain rod brackets will have a [Set Screw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_screw), which is used to prevent the rod from moving.

[image]

If your bracket does not have a set screw, check to see if there is a hole where one should be.

[image]

If you have a hole but no screw, you'll have to find a screw that will fit in the hole.  Make sure it's a [Machine Screw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw#Machine_screws) with a flat end (not pointy), so it will work properly. Finding the proper size screw might be a bit of a challenge, so it's probably a good idea to take the bracket with you to the hardware store.

If you don't have a hole for a set screw; or any other mechanism to prevent the rod from moving, you might be able to add your own.  Doing so will require a [drill motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill), the proper [drill bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill_bit), a [center punch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_(tool)#Central) (*if the bracket is metal*),and a [tap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_and_die#Tap).

Comment: +1 and also I'll say that this is the most reliable and durable curtain rod design I've ever seen. It's often ignored because of being "not aesthetic" but other designs usually result in very poor reliability.